# Best Practices for Client-Side Logging and Error Handling in React Native

Tags: react-native, debugging, logging, remote-debugging

I am doing a project in react native in which I want write and read logger for debugging when app run at the client-side.
my question is how to write / read logger(debug logging) in react native app. or how to use remote-debugging in react native.

Comment: Are you searching for something like firebase carashlytics ?

Comment: No , I am searching related to client-side error handling.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Are you asking how you can debug your react native app ?

Comment: I want debug and find error of release app in react native

Comment: If you want to see errors when the app crashes on a user device you need something like firebase crashlytics otherwise if you want to debug the app while you are developing it you can use react native debugging tools like Chrome developer tools or flipper

Comment: Give me an example of what you want to do

Comment: how to help via firebase any blog for understanding?

Comment: See the official documentation: https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage

Comment: If this is what you are searching for tell me to edit your question and write this as an answer

Comment: its work for releasing app?

Answer (score 3):

The official documents suggest the methods you want

[react-native-debugging](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging)

If you want to check for errors in the release app, you can use the following library.

[sentry document](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/)

Comment: please let me know which part of react-native-debugging help me what i want

Comment: @vishu React Developer Tools or Chrome Developer Tools in addition, you may use a flipper.

Comment: I want debug and find error of release app in react native when app run client-side then how to track  and handle error.

Comment: @vishu In the case of debug, use React Developer Tools or Chrome Developer Tools. For releases, use Sentry.